# Is it possible to destroy a dotcloud service from within itself?

Tags: dotcloud

I have a dotcloud service which I want to configure such that it shuts down and destroys itself after it has completed its task.

This should mean I am not charged for more server time than I actually require.

The obvious way to do this would be from the dotcloud CLI, but this is not installed on dotcloud instances.  Also the dotcloud user does not have privilege to run the `shutdown` command.

Is there a simple way to do this, or would I need to deploy a custom service which installs the dotcloud CLI and from that can then destroy itself?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way for a service to destroy itself, but you could, as you've described, install the CLI and your credentials (I'd suggest using your API key in an environment variable set via `dotcloud env set`) and then script the `dotcloud destroy -A <app name> <servicename>` call.

A more efficient approach would be to have a permanent worker and keep feeding it jobs to do. The dotCloud platform is best suited for applications which have relatively consistent RAM needs, since we don't offer autoscaling.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  Is there a custom recipe for the dotcloud env?  Or should it just be a python service?

Comment: You should be able to install the dotcloud CLI just by adding ``dotcloud`` to your ``requirements.txt`` file in a python service (that's the same as if you'd done ``pip install dotcloud``).

Comment: Any reason not to set API key via dotcloud.yml?

Comment: That is a good way to set it for just one service, but if you need to change the value later, using ``dotcloud env set`` might be better (though it will share the key with all your services)